# Showing that either $v$ is an eigenvector for $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ or else $(A − \lambda \operatorname{Id})v$ is an eigenvector for $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose the $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ has repeated eigenvalues $\lambda$. Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Using the fact that a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ always satisfies its own characteristic equation. (That is, if $\lambda^2 + \alpha\lambda + \beta = 0$ is the characteristic equation associated to $A$, then the matrix $A^2 + \alpha A + \beta I$ is the $0$ matrix), I must show that either $v$ is an eigenvector for $A$ or else $(A − \lambda \operatorname{Id})v$ is an eigenvector for $A$.

I know that if the matrix has repeated eigenvalues the characteristic polynomial should look like $(a-\lambda)^2 - bc = 0$ for $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & a \end{bmatrix}$. I am stuck on using the fact that $A$ satisfies its own polynomial to show the final result. Also once I have shown $(A-\lambda \operatorname{Id})v$ is an eigenvector if $v$ is not do I need to show the other direction, i.e. that $v$ is an eigenvector if $(A-\lambda \operatorname{Id})v$ is not?

Comment: Your deduction about what the characteristic polynomial looks like is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you given that $a=d$? Because that neither implies, nor is implied by, the fact that $A$ has a repeated eigenvalue. Rather, your characteristic polynomial will be $(x-\lambda)^2$, so you know $(A-\lambda I)^2=O$.

So, for any $\mathbf{v}$ you have $(A-\lambda I)(A-\lambda I)\mathbf{v}=(A-\lambda I)^2 \mathbf{v}=O\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$.

Therefore, either $(A-\lambda I)\mathbf{v}$ is already zero, or it's an eigenvector.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lambda$ be the single repeated eigenvalue of $A$; then the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(x)$ is well-known to be

$\chi_A(x) = x^2 - 2\lambda x + \lambda^2, \tag 1$

which may be written as

$\chi_A(x) = x^2 - 2 \lambda x + \lambda^2 = (x - \lambda)^2, \tag 2$

since

$\text{trace}(A) = \lambda + \lambda = 2\lambda, \; \det(A) = \lambda \lambda = \lambda^2; \tag 3$

by Cayley-Hamilton, $A$ satisfies $\chi_A(x)$, hence

$(A - \lambda)^2 = 0; \tag 4$

this may be written in the form

$A(A - \lambda) - \lambda(A - \lambda) = (A - \lambda)^2 = 0, \tag 5$

or

$A(A - \lambda) = \lambda(A - \lambda); \tag 6$

suppose $V$ is *not* an eigenvector of $A$; then we have

$AV \ne \lambda V, \tag 7$

or

$W = (A - \lambda)V \ne 0; \tag 8$

then *via* (6),

$AW = A(A - \lambda)V = \lambda (A - \lambda)V = \lambda W, \tag 9$

and since as has been mentioned in (8)

$W \ne 0, \tag{10}$

we see that

$(A - \lambda)V = W \tag{11}$

is an eigenvector of $A$.